# Underline letter in win form label without adding hotkey

Tags: .net, winforms

I have a .Net 3.5 windows form application wherein I have a series of label controls below some icons. Those labels are triggered by Ctrl + [underlined letter] (not Alt+Key). I want to underline a letter in the label without making it a hotkey. I tried hijacking the paint event, but I couldn't figure out how to center align the text (label is center aligned below its icon) and/or draw that underline.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the level properties and find the Text property. add a '&'  infront of the letter that u want to underline. for example

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsC5T.png
```

or you can do this form code by adding the following Line

```
this.label1.Text = "Add &Bank";
```

Comment: Adding a '&' will make it a hotkey. I am looking for a non-hotkey solution.